# appcompat-v7 update cancels the Toolbar text color customization

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

Updating **support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1** to **insupportablement-v7:23.1.0** resulted in cancelling the title and menu text color customization of the **support.v7.widget.Toolbar**.

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Here's the displayed toolbar before and after the update.

[image: Before the update]

[image: After the update]

Constraints:

- Use the latest version of appcompat (currently 23.1.0)
- Change toolbar theme but not the whole app theme
- minSdkVersion 14
- MainActivity extends FragmentActivity (I don't want to extend ActionBarActivity)

Updating the version of appcompat seems to cancel the effect of **textColorPrimary** and **textColorSecondary** (see **styles.xml** below).

The only difference in code occurs in **appcompat-v7** and of course **compileSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** (see the two files **build.gradle (Module: app)** below)

Here are all the necessary code files to test the two situations :

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myapplication;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main)
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:title="Refresh"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle (Module: app)** THIS OLD VERSION WORKS !

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

**build.gradle (Module: app)** THIS NEW VERSION DOES NOT WORK !!

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Check this [link](http://androhub.com/android-toolbar/).

Comment: Your link is interesting but could not help me with the constraints I have.

Comment: Same problem here, have you solved it Hic Hr?

Comment: @Struct no, I haven't solved it. I've tried every update after the 22.1.1 but in vain. Still the same problem :( How about you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved this:

First thing I tried was to set it in `onCreate` `toolbar.setTitleTextColor(....);` , it works but it's not a good solution.

So I started working with the styles and  found a solution that works for me:

In **styles.xml** add the style

```
<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar.Title" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Then in the toolbar add the attribute `app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.Title"`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                   android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                   android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                                   android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                                   app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
                                   app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.Title" />
```

**EDIT:**

Use android:theme and if you need to style the menu use app:popupTheme

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                   android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                   android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                                   android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                                   android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
                                   app:popupTheme="@style/MyMenuStyle"
                                    />
```

Comment: Thx. Perfect for the title color. Remains the menu color (the 3 dots in the top right of the toolbar) that needs to be also white. if possible, please provide the full solution.

Comment: @HichemAcher see the EDIT

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the solution, these are the full changes :

In **activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />
```

In **styles.xml**

```
 <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
```